# Kafka Connect, get Json Schema for JsonConverter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, thrift, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up **kafka-connector** with a **custom value converter**.

I'm using kafka to transfer serialised thrift objects.
I want to set up a kafka-connector which is deserialising thrift-messages, converting them to json and sending to elasticsearch.

Method `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter#toConnectData` returns `SchemaAndValue`, which needs `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema`.
**How do I get this schema for my json?**

What I tried so far:

I tried to extend `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, but It has it's own schema coming from somewhere.

I tried to generate schema using this library: https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema, but `JsonConverter` seems to have it's own format: it expects `map` instead of `object`, etc.
See: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L408

Despite that I have disable schema (`"value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"`) in my config, the connector is still crashing and complaining about schema. **Where is this schema coming from? How do they generate it?**

I'm going to write a method which is recursively renaming all "wrong" things in json schema, but that's too awkward. **Is there a proper approach?**

UPD: My config is

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "mytopic",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "https://my-elastic:443",
    "type.name": "event",
    "elasticsearch.index.prefix" : "kafka",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter" : "com.example.ThriftToJsonDeserializer",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
}
```

Comment: Message has to be in `json` format and contain: `schema` and `payload`. You can read more: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained#json-schemas

Comment: thank you, @wardziniak. This link covers a lot of what I'm describing here, but the problem still remains:
1) How do they generate their-style Schema (with "struct" and `fields` instead of `object` and `properties`)   
2) I have "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false", as they say in the article, but the connector still complains about the schema:
```org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Cannot infer mapping without schema.
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.Mapping.inferMapping(Mapping.java:83)```

Comment: Could you add your connector configuration? Have you tried with `schema.ignore=true`.

Comment: @wardziniak I believe you mean `schema.enabled=false`? (which is part of the question)

Comment: What is this `com.example.ThriftToJsonDeserializer` ? How are you passing configurations to it? The `JsonConverter` is the only Converter that has this schema enabled config - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L285

Comment: Alternatively, write a Kafka Streams job to do the conversion to a new topic in JSON... Or  perhaps you can base your code on the Protobuf converter, except for Thrift? https://github.com/blueapron/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter

Comment: @cricket_007, no, I mean `schema.ignore` which is elasticsearch connector property

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Elasticsearch Connector tries to infer mapping for elasticsearch based on message schema. Message schema is created by the `Converter` and modified by `Transforms`. 
If you set `value.converter.schemas.enable` on `false` your records schemas are nulls.

You have to set `schema.ignore` to true and Elasticsearch Connector won't infer schema.

Comment: How can we filter the JSON data in Elastic Search Sink Connector?